# Replicating the effect of CSS "background-image" - alternative approaches?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm seeking a way to implement a full-size responsive background image like the one that can be achieved using the CSS below, except that I require also that my background be animatable (able to be faded using Jquery).

Here's the CSS that gives me the desired effect on my landing page:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(images/lovelyphoto.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
  /* bg color while image loads */
}
```

I need the background-image then to fade when the visitor clicks a "take a tour" button -- achieved using Jquery, which also renders new html into the DOM, including a new background image to be faded in. But when I apply the following Jquery, it's not able to achieve a smooth transition, I believe because the background-image CSS property is not animatable (see: w3schools, "Animatable Properties": https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $("body").fadeOut(1200, function() {
      $("body").html('<body>/* new html goes here */ </body>').fadeIn(1200);
      setTimeout(fadeToPageThree, 6 * 1000); // sets timer for pg2 to pg3 transition
    }); // closes first page fadeOut
  }); // closes click handler
});
```

The solution that I've been attempting is to get rid of the css background-image and instead place my background image as an  tag inside the html. This solves my fade problem, because Jquery can handle a fade on this img element, but it doesn't give me the responsive effects that the CSS applied to the body above does, no matter what css styles on width, height, min-width, etc that I attempt to apply to the img.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go the route of using an image tag, you can get a functionality similar to

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

By doing this:

```
div.parent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

You can then transition opacity on the `img` tag or use jQuery's `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` or whatever.

In order for this to really work well, you will need an appropriately large background image, or else you'll have to be okay with the image not stretching to the full width of the page. (You can force it to stretch by setting width and height both equal to 100%, assuming the container is as large as the page, but then you'll lose the background-image-like behavior, and it'll just stretch/distort itself to fill the container.)

Try running and expanding this snippet to full screen, then resizing your browser:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  bottom: -100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?image=1084" alt="">
```

You can adjust the values for positioning and margin to get different effects as far as how the image is cropped as you shrink the browser down. For example, if we wanted to keep the right part of the image visible as the image is cropped, we can do `left: 0`, `right: 0`, `margin-left: auto`, `margin-right: 0`.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -100%;
  margin: auto 0 auto auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?image=1084" alt="">
```

Comment: Thanks for this, @cjl750, it works for me. I've begun implementing it in my code and haven't had major problems, with Jquery now able to fade in and out smoothly. Is there a way to adjust preferences for which part of the image appears on resize? For example, say we wanted your walrus on the right to remain visible as the window narrows, deeming this the most important part of the image to show, no matter window size.

Comment: @Dan-in-Austin Yes, by adjusting the position and margin values, you can get different effects. I have edited my answer to show how you could keep the rightmost portion of the image visible as you size the browser down. P.S. If either my or Chris's answer eventually works out for you, make sure to come back and accept whichever one you settled on.

Comment: Hey! Checking back in after working with this solution in my code, and I've accepted your answer. However, I've found I get a sometimes buggy appearance on devices with a high height to width ration, for instance on iPhone5 and iPhone6, or Galaxy Note3, but not on iPhone 4, at least according to testing I've done using Chrome developer tools. What's strange about this is that it doesn't always seem to happen. Sometimes the image covers only part of the page, with unwanted overflow (from the previous underlying image) appearing at the bottom part of the window, sometimes not, and it works fine.

Comment: @Dan-in-Austin hmmmm. In regards to the bug, hard to say just based on that description what the problem would be or the fix. I've had Chrome's device preview spaz out on me before and show things wrong, and closing/reopening it usually fixes that problem. But if you're seeing problems consistently, it's probably an issue with your code or the picture's aspect ratio. Fool-proof method would be to use an image big enough to always cover the whole screen at any screen size. Or you could show different versions of each image on mobile that're specially cropped to better fit tall, narrow screens.

Answer (score 1):

You could flip it round - instead of fading out the image, fade in something on top of it. You keep the image as a background image on `body`, with all the advantages you like, and add a fixed background layer `<div>` on top of it, the same colour as your default body background colour. When you want to "fade out" the background image, you instead fade *in* the background layer that sits on top, and the effect would be identical. Your CSS would be something like:

```
#background-overlay {

  background-color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 800ms;

  position: fixed;
  z-index: -10000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

#background-overlay.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And then in your jQuery you'd just add `$('#background-overlay').addClass('show')` when you want to "fade out" the body background.

Comment: Interesting idea, Chris, I'll try applying this and get back to you about it to let you know whether it works for me. Really appreciate your thought on this.

Comment: Hi Chris, I've gone with your idea of fading in the new background overlays, but the css provided does not replicate the CSS 'cover' effect for 'background-image' that I was seeking, it instead distorts the image on resize. The contributor below added a solution for that, however, so combining your two approaches I've been able to get the effect that I had needed. Thanks again!